# Is there a way to trace each message in Akka?

Tags: akka, trace

For the debugging and test, I want to trace each message which was sent to actor and received by the actor. Is there any way to turn on such logging without changing the code? Or maybe there is any free library or other tools which can do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is documented [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/logging.html).

Essentially, you can use the following:

```
akka {
  actor {
    debug {
      # enable function of LoggingReceive, which is to log any received message at
      # DEBUG level
      receive = on
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this option is not documented in the Java documentation - I'm not sure if it works for java.

Comment: The above logging configuration works only if an actor uses the [`LoggingReceive`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/event/LoggingReceive.html) decorator.

Comment: Exactly, it works only when receive method is decoredted.